# Laravel Concat - Syntax or Access Violation

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

Trying to write an MySQL Query to search on users based on two columns :

**first_name**

**surname**

I'd like to Concatenate first_name and surname as name and then write a search query based on that.

I've currently written some PHP code, But I keep getting the error :

> SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an
>   error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your
>   MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near '%?%' at line
>   1 (SQL: select `users`.* from `users` where CONCAT(`first_name`, ' ',
>   `surname`) LIKE %Stu%)

My current PHP code is as follows :

```
// Search Based on Q..
$q = $request->input('q');

$results = User::select('users.*')->WhereRaw("CONCAT(`first_name`, ' ', `surname`) LIKE %?%", [$q])->get();
```

I suspect I'm just getting the syntax wrong, But any help would be appreciated.

Thank You!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Move `%` to parameter:

```
$results = User::select('users.*')
    ->WhereRaw("CONCAT(`first_name`, ' ', `surname`) LIKE ?", ['%' . $q . '%'])
    ->get();
```

Answer (score 1):

two errors in your query first `as fullname` not mention and second `like operator`.. i have fix these errors

```
$q = $request->input('q');
     $results = User::select('users.*')
     ->WhereRaw("CONCAT(`first_name`, ' ', `surname`) as fullname
     LIKE ?", ['%' . $q . '%'])->get();
```